# Hacer un Insert de un listado

Tags: mysql

alguna forma de poder rralziar un insert de un numero grande de una lista que tengo de una forma facil si tener que crear un insert por cada fila?? os dejo un ejemplo.

la lista seria esto (www,aaa,sss,ddd,eee,lll)

```
INSERT INTO `imaginarq`.`arqueologia` (`url`) VALUES ('www');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que separar por coma cada valor:

```sql
INSERT INTO `imaginarq`.`arqueologia` (`url`) VALUES ('www'), ('aaa'),('sss'),('ddd'),('eee'),('lll');
```